# WooCommerce 404s

Tags: woocommerce, http-status-code-404, permalinks

So I've been building a custom theme with WooCommerce integration, but I'm having a weird issue with the permalink structure. I simply want my shop structure to work like this: "example.com/shop/category/product/"

My pages and link structure are built to reflect this, but I get a 404 when trying to view a category "/shop/category/".

Note that viewing a product page in a category still works perfectly fine without a 404 and the url reflects "/shop/category/product/".

My Permalink settings:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

- Fill out "Product Category Base" field with "category"
- Fill out "Product Tag Base" field with "product"
- Then "Save"

I hope it will work for you.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix it, I cleared my cache to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the woocommerce permalinks description:

1. Default – this is not a user-friendly structure of permalinks and the URL looks the following way: /?product=product-11
2. Product based permalinks do not have the shop part in the URL and look the following way: /product/product-5/
3. Shop base permalinks include the /shop/ slug in the URL, so it looks like this: /shop/product-9/
4. Shop base with category permalinks include both shop slug and category slug and they are most suitable for SEO. Here is how the permalink looks like: /shop/category-1/product-4/

"Shop base with category" as I see that you have already selected. Now just save Permalinks once and please try a different web browser to ignore cache issue or clear site cache if you are using any cache plugin.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I've ruled out that it's a cache or browser issue, I know it's not even a template issue because if I use the default setting all my pages work, just not with the desired URL structure.